# Restriction of some representation of $D_{12}$

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $D_{12}$ be the dihedral group, $\langle  x,y: x^2 = y^6 =1 , xy = y^{-1}x \rangle$ and $K = \langle xy \rangle \times  \langle y^3 \rangle $ be a subgroup.Let $\xi^2$ denote a representation of $D_{12}$ which sends y to rotation by $2\pi/3$ matrix in $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$  and sends $x$ to reflexion by $x$-axis.

What is $Res_{K}^{D_{12}}(\xi^2)$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question?

Comment: @Servaes :I think that'll be trivial  +  sign representation.Because $\xi^2|_{<y^3>}$ is trivial and $\xi^2|_{<xy>}$ is just $1+ sign.$

Comment: Sounds good to me. What part of proving this are you having trouble with?

Comment: Thank you. I have done both the parts. I want to ask another question: Is $D_{12}/K$ embed equivariantly in $S(\xi^2)? $ Where $S(\xi^2)$ is sphere in $\xi^2.$

Comment: What do you mean by $D_{12}/K$? Note that $K$ is not normal in $D_{12}$...

Comment: Actually $D_{12}/K$ is not a group but a $D_{12}-$space.

Comment: Okay, so it is a $D_{12}$-space of three elements? Then what do you mean by $S(\xi^2)$ being the sphere in $\xi^2$?

Comment: $S(\xi^2) = \{ v \in \xi^2 : ||v|| = 1\}.$ It is also a $D_{12}-$space.

Comment: I seem to be confused; I thought $\xi^2$ was a representation?

Comment: You can think $G$- representation as a vector space with a $G$ action.

Comment: Then no: The action of $K$ on $D_{12}/K$ is trivial whereas the action of $K$ on $S(\xi^2)$ has only two fixed points.